# Mosaic multiple multi-band rasters into a single multi-band raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic, multi-band

I have >50 four band rasters that I would like to mosaic into a single four band raster. SAGA mosaic doesn't seem to work since it flattens the rasters out and combines them into a single band mosaic. Building Virtual rasters retains the four bands but does not mosaic so not very helpful across my study area.

Are there any other options for me in QGIS to explore? This seems obvious but I am unable to find something that may work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mosaic tool in Orfeo toolbox (OTB) or download the free [OTB Monteverdi](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/tag/monteverdi/). If you want to setup the OTB to be run from QGIS, you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html). Then, you can find the Mosaic tool under the `OTB -> Image Manipulation -> Mosaic`:

[image]

Based on the [tutorial: OTB Monteverdi Image Mosaic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hShRRWc9IWQ), it looks like it supports mosaic multispectral images.

Comment: I would just like to add that under the 'harmonisation method' one needs to select band for the seamless mosaic to occur. Thanks once again. This works well.

Comment: @VGu You are welcome. I am glad it solved your question. :)